# Automated reverse image search

Tags: windows, file-management, automation, search-engine, image-recognition

I'm a huge sucker when it comes to photography, so I tend to download a lot of images and store them locally. Now, because it's often quite a lot I don't always manually do a (quick) reverse image search to see if a higher quality version is available, so I end up with a lot of low quality versions of otherwise stunning images.

Because of this, I've been looking for a piece of software that will run a search for all files in a folder and if it finds a picture of higher quality (larger file size) simply download that image and replace the old one, sort of like Visipics, except via (google) image search.

I've been unable to find such a piece of software so figured I'd ask about here.